# jquery popup close function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I have button on my mobile website. I want to do following:

when I press the button the popup should appear. This popup should contain some text and a OK button. When I press Ok button the popup should disapear, nothing else. The page should stay in the same conditions.

My code is as follows:

```
<a id="edit-btn2" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" data-position-to="window" class= "edit-button1"  data-role="button" href="#popupPanel"></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupPanel" data-dismissible='false' data-corners="false" data-theme="b"  style="height:100px; width:300px;">
  <p>This is just a demonstrator</p>
  <button href="#" id= "popup-button"  data-theme="c" data-icon="false" data-mini="false"  >OK</button>
</div>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
$( "#popup-button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#popupPanel" ).popup( "close" );
});
```

Current situation is:

When I click on the ok button it works for the very first time but not latter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a>` instead of `<button>`. Your code should look like this:

```
<a id="edit-btn2" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slide" data-position-to="window" class="edit-button1" data-role="button" href="#popupPanel"></a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupPanel" data-dismissible="false" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" style="height:100px; width:300px;">
  <p>This is just a demonstrator</p>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" id="popup-button" data-theme="c" data-icon="false" data-mini="false" >OK</a>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alfredbez/pwhEk/)

I've also added

```
data-role="button" data-rel="back"
```

Javascript isn't necessary in this case

Comment: Oddly, your code no longer works... or at least it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Class instead of id for button.

Html - button

```
href="#" class= "popup-button"  data-theme="c" data-icon="false" data-mini="false"
```

JavaScript

```
$( ".popup-button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#popupPanel" ).popup( "close" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `pageinit` and use correct event binding using `.on`.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("#popup-button").on("click", function () {
        $("#popupPanel").popup("close");
    });
});
```

Or, add `data-rel="back"` attribute to `button`. However, if you wish to use this, it's safer to add `data-history="false"` in order not to go back to previous page.

```
<button href="#" id= "popup-button"  data-theme="c" data-rel="back" data-history="false">OK</button>
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZzWvD/)**