# On Asp.net page why jquery close button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, popup

I work with an Asp.net and C#. When I click on a button to show the message I get one popup box, but when I click close button on popup box it’s not closing the popup.

aspx page syntax:

```
<div id='dialog-page' title="Modal">
</div>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnModal" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick="javascript:return showDialog(this.name);"></asp:LinkButton>
```

jQuery code:

```
function showDialog(uniqueName) {
            var url = "ReportGenerationSingleACView.aspx?id=";
            var temp=document.getElementById('<% =txtCustomerID.ClientID%>').value;   
            url=url+temp;         

        $("#dialog-page").load(url).dialog({
                                        title: "AC View Details",
                                        autoOpen: false,
                                        resizable: true,
                                        height: 400,
                                        width: 600,                                          
                                        modal: true, 
                                        buttons: 
                                        {
                                            Close: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                                        }       
                            });                                


        $('#dialog-page').dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
```

Here is some more information about the popup  work but those not work for me:

Stack Overflow question: [jQuery Pop up not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213330/jquery-popup-close-function-not-working)

Why is it not working for me? How to handle or what am I missing? Help me solve this issue.

If have any questions, please ask - thank you in advance, any type of suggestion will be acceptable.

**Note:** Popup X icon works properly and close button also fired but popup not close

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that `{$(this).dialog("close");}` targets on the dialog. So you try to close the dialog in your dialog and there are none.

Try out `{$(parent).dialog("close");}` instead or pass the function to the parent page.

Comment: Lorin thanks for your reply ,use {$(parent).dialog("close");} not working.

Comment: Hm, ok. Could you debug the close function then? 
Change $(this).dialog("close"); to 
var myObject = $(this);
myObject.dialog("close"); 
and see if the myObject has a method dialog() or not. Can be that the function itself is not fired or that the message is wrong.

Comment: Lorin, i put alert on close button portion it's working show me message. my used syntax is Close: function () {
                    var myObject = $(this); myObject.dialog("close");
                    alert(myObject);
                 }

Comment: Shamim, yes, but you still dont know what type myObject is. Could you set a breakpoint at the line myObject.dialog("close"); and look inside of the myObject?

Comment: Lorin, sorry if i dont make any mistake it's can not see javascript close event variable value in debug mode.full jquery function how to debug.